# How to correctly implement a multi-window application in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# Winforms application which supports multiple windows, similar to a browser.

At the moment, when the user launches a new window, I just find the process name and launch the process again.  This seems like a bit of a hack, and it comes with the extra problem that the new window has to do a lot of redundant application initialization work.

I tried this:

```
var form = new MainForm();
form.Show()
```

But this has the hidden caveat that closing the main window (which looks like any other window) results in closing all windows.

How can I make my program behave like a browser, where each window is independent but we don't launch a new process every time?

(Note: I think Chrome is an exception in that it launches a new process for each window!)

Comment: You could try Application.Run(new MainForm()) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DanielKelley Thanks for that, but it seems to crash; I get an exception saying "Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead"

Comment: You need to create a new foreground thread for each call to `Application.Run`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a new window:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Application.Run(new MainForm()))
{
    IsBackground = false
};

thread.Start();
```

Obviously, this implies that if you access shared state from multiple threads, you need to properly synchronize that access.

Comment: This doesn't compile (parenthesis & curly braces don't match up it seems)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MDI containers to support multiple windows. Your MainForm will contain all other forms. Other forms can work independent.

Set your main form, MDI container property to true. When creating new form, set mdi parent to your main form.