# How to open the two forms at run time using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms, one of which is the `keyboard` and the other with the `text field`.

But when the forms load, the form with the text field becomes active and then I can't use the keyboard.

It's working fine with notepad.

[image]

[image]

I want to write to the text field using my keyboard.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164909/how-to-correctly-implement-a-multi-window-application-in-c

Comment: Where is your code? All we have are screenshots.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I developed the keyboard because I'm gonna use this in touch screen LED. @JohnG

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to show multiple form at the same time
Assume that you run this code from button click of main form

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();

form1.Show(this);
form2.Show(this);
```

The **this** keyword is optional, and can be removed.

p.s: I suggest use correct naming in your app to help better coding and debugging. Something like keyboardForm instead of form2 will be more readable and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The thing was, I want to write to the text field using my own forms keyboard.

here is the code I found (mentioned by @RandRandom) and post

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Application.Run(new MainForm()))
{
  IsBackground = false
};

thread.Start();
```

This works because this is, not to fall the second form (keyboardForm) in the background